# Array is not being populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

To iterate over a json file I use :

```
var list = new Array();
$.getJSON("json.js", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function () {
        $.each(this, function (k, v) {
            var list = new Array();
            console.log(v.value);
            list.push(v.value);
        });
    });
    console.log(list.length);
});
```

The json file :

```
{
    "quotes": [
    {
        "value": "q1"
    },
    {
        "value": "q2"
    },
    {
        "value": "q3"
    }
]
}
```

But the size of the list is zero.

Here is the console output :

```
q1 
q2 
q3 
0
```

Why is this occuring ?

Comment: Try removing the second `var list = new Array()`. Your pushing to a local variable, then console.logging the public variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring a new array in the each, just remove this line :

```
var list = new Array();
```

Keep the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `var`, `list` is only defined in the anonymous function created by this code:

```
$.each(this, function (k, v) {
    var list = new Array();
    console.log(v.value);
    list.push(v.value);
});
```

This is called variable scope. The `list` that you modify in this function is not the same as the `list` declared in the first line of your code, because one is global and the other local.